# NodeJS stream issue while reading file and inserting data in the DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I am reading file through the stream and there is one problem where I need to validate email id of the user given in the CSV file.

Here ar the scenario.

1. If given user's email id is already match in the file then don't allow that record to be inserted.
2. If there are multiple emails in the text file and I insert those then all the records gets inserted and this is not validating emails.

```
    if(req.file.size < 10485760) {
                let success = 0
                let fail = 0

                fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
                .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
                .on('data', row => {
                    row.user_id = contractorID
                    row.created_by = loggedUserID

                    CustomerSchema.findAll({
                        where: {
                            email: row.email.toLowerCase(),
                            user_id: contractorID,
                            is_deleted: 0
                        }
                    }).then(result => {
                        if(result.length > 0) {
                            fail += 1
                            // console.log(fail)
                        } else {
                            console.log("----------else----------")
                            CustomerSchema.create(row).then((customer) => {
                                success += 1
                            }).catch(err => {
                                return res.sendToEncode({
                                    status: 0,
                                    message: "Something went wrong while inserting customers."
                                })
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }).on('end', function() {
                    let s = this;
                    s.destroy();
                }).on('close', function() {
                    res.sendToEncode({
                        status: 200,
                        message: "Data imported successfully.",
                        data: {
                            "success": success,
                            "fail": fail
                        }
                    })
                }).on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return res.sendToEncode({
                        status: 0,
                        message: "Please check your file and make sure it is comma seperated csv file."
                    })
                })
            } else {
                return res.sendToEncode({
                    status: 0,
                    message: "File size can not be more than 10MB"
                })
            }
```

Is there any way to count the inserted and duplicate record ?

Thanks.

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: @JDunken I am using MySQL